# Using scale_y_continuous & scale_y_reverse concurrently

Tags: r

I'm currently using the following code to get rid of the space between the first tick mark and the y-axis, but I also want to reverse the direction of the y-axis. How would I accomplish both at the same time? Here's the code I have so far:

```
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(min(dfplot[,1])-5, max(dfplot[,1])+5), expand = c(0, 0))
```

Here, with `expand = c(0, 0)`, I am successfully able to eliminate that gap between the first tick and the axis, but I want to reverse the y-axis direction. How would I successfully accomplish both? I've tried `scale_y_reverse(limits = c(min(dfplot[,1])-5, max(dfplot[,1])+5), expand = c(0, 0))` but that just results in me not being able to see ony half of my graph figure, and parts of it disappear.

Comment: When I run it, it says `Error in c(max(dfplot[, 1]) + 5, min(dfplot[, 1]) - 5, ) : 
  argument 3 is empty` I think something is missing after the comma

Comment: Works perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reverse the limits, because you're reversing the axis too. So `max` goes first, and `min` second.

```
scale_y_reverse(limits = c(max(dfplot[,1])+5, min(dfplot[,1])-5), expand = c(0, 0))
```